# Get values of one form into another form in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get an integer value of one form (Form1) inside another form (Form2). I have tried to access it via the below code but not getting it. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Points As Integer = 100

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = Points
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim FinalPoints As New Form1
        Label1.Text = FinalPoints.Label1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data between forms DIRECTLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738223/passing-data-between-forms-directly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we pass data from one opened form to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204773/how-can-we-pass-data-from-one-opened-form-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: As you are showing your Form2 (Form2_Load is executed), a new Form1 is created. This newly created Form1 has NOT executed the Form1_Load function yet!

You would need to show the newly created FinalPoints (Form1) with FinalPoints.Show() like that:

```
Dim FinalPoints As New Form1
FinalPoints.Show()
Label1.Text = FinalPoints.Label1.Text
```

to let the Form1_Load function execute, which is then setting your FinalPoints.Label1.Text. But that would just opens a new Form1.

Also you can just get the public Points variable inside the Form2_Load like that (you also do not have to create a new Form1):

```
Label1.Text = Form1.Points
```

Alternatively: Just use a public variable inside Form2 and assign your value to it, before you show the form.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Points As Integer = 100

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = Points.ToString
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FinalPoints As New Form2
        FinalPoints.StringFromForm1 = Label1.Text
        FinalPoints.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form2
    Public Property StringFromForm1 As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = StringFromForm1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `Dim FinalPoints As New Form1` creates a *new* instance of Form1, but what you want is to refer to an *existing* instance of Form1. There are different techniques you can try. For example, **overload** the Show method of Form2.

Something like this:

Form1: pass the value to Form2

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form2

    Me.Hide()

    f.Show(Points)
End Sub
```

Form2: fetch the value from caller (Form1)

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Overloads Sub Show(ByVal Points As Integer)
        Me.Label1.Text = Points.ToString
        MyBase.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```